# PHP parse question

Tags: php, preg-match, substring

Here is code I use for grabbing thumbnails paths from a site

```
$thumbslist = $xpath->query('//div[@class="g-catThumb"]/img/@src');
foreach($thumbslist as $f){
            echo $f->nodeValue;
            echo "<br/>";
        }
```

I have the following output: `/toys/16462/medium.jpg` 
How should I get only 16462. Thaks in advance.

Comment: Will this always be in the form of `/foldername/number/imagename.extension`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string by slashes into an array, and grab the piece you want.

```
$segments = explode('/', $f->nodeValue);
echo $segments[1]; // Second segment
```

Make sure to check if it `isset()` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo array_pop(explode('/', dirname($f->nodeValue)));
```

Comment: Nice solution with `dirname()`, seems foolproof and probably exactly what OP wants. I'm sure there's about a million other ways to do this but this seems quite elegant.